# How to run meteor application on two or more Heroku dynos?

Tags: heroku, scalability, meteor

I have Meteor application which is run on Heroku platform using 1 dyno. When I increase number of dynos it stops working, reporting some problems with XHR (ERROR 404) on client side.

Does anybody successfully run Meteor app on two or more Heroku dynos? If so, what should I do in order to get it working?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, unfortunately Meteor does not work on Heroku with more than one dyno.  Meteor needs session affinity, which Heroku does not currently offer.

Meteor needs session affinity: [Running meteor in a cluster and real-time changes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13201269/running-meteor-in-a-cluster-and-real-time-changes/13716069)

Heroku does not support session affinity: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/intro-for-java-developers

Comment: Has this changed? Can meteor now work on Heroku with more than one dyno?

Comment: Heroku now supports session affinity (in labs): https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/session-affinity

Answer (score 1):

If you want a SaaS hosting provider that supports Meteor and can scale to multiple dynos using session affinity, there is now a CloudBees buildpack which looks promising:

https://github.com/CloudBees-community/meteor-clickstart

Answer (score 1):

Heroku now supports session affinity, which allows it to work with Meteor. It's in labs at the time of writing this, so you'll have to enable it.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/session-affinity

Answer (score 0):

Well, Session affinity (or something similar) appears to be in the roadmap, at the very least.  So, the developers anticipating addressing the issue by the time they release version 1.0.

https://trello.com/board/meteor-roadmap/508721606e02bb9d570016ae

Comment: Actually, what is on the Meteor roadmap is being able to run multiple Meteor server instances without having a ten second delay for data changes to be propagated from one server to another (currently the only communication between servers is through the database, which is polled every ten seconds).  Even with Meteor 1.0 the hosting environment will still need to be able to supply client session affinity for Meteor to work with multiple server instances.

Comment: So, it seems that the question can be converted to whether or not the hosting provider (in this case, Heroku), has load balancers that support sticky sessions and sessionids in the cookies.  After digging around on this topic a bit more, it seems like once that's in place, it's a matter of implementing socksjs with Meteor, yes?