# Meteor Heroku Deploy Error Code 400

Tags: heroku, meteor

I have deployed an app too heroku and am getting a client side error of `WebSocket connection to 'herokuapp.com/sockjs/047/sbumyk1y/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400`. I am using 2 - 2x dynos for the app. How can I fix this client side error?  I have found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14417193/how-to-run-meteor-application-on-two-or-more-heroku-dynos) but that was over two years ago and the post states that it was intended to be in version 1.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exact problem is unknown, but one suspected reason was the inability for meteor apps to run on multiple heroku dynos. Instead I deployed my application to Modulus and everything now works great.

One resource:
http://joshowens.me/modulus-vs-heroku-vs-digital-ocean/